# Adding multiple rows to table with auto_increment column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im trying to insert Data into a table named team. The table holds 4 colums. selection_id(primary key), player_name, position, and fixture id.

The selection_id has a value of auto_increment. Im adding the player names and position to the table. However the problem is, for each value it extracts out of the arrays, $playnames and $positions, the selection_id updates. Like this: 
[image]

This is not what I want. 5 names should be stored (thus storing the team selected) in the table **before** the selection_id updates. **OR** for each new row, where a new team selection is made, the selection_id must be the same.

Im not sure how to get around this problem. I thought about doing another query after the data has been inserted to overwrite the selection_id and making all the rows (in this case) equal to 117. But im sure this is not the most effecient way to do it.

If anyone can give me a couple of pointers it would be greatly appreciated.
Code follows:

```
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    $player_ids = array_map('intval', $_REQUEST['players']);

    var_dump($player_ids);

    $query = 'SELECT `name`, `position` 
        FROM `player_info` 
        WHERE `player_id` IN (' . implode(',', $player_ids) . ')';

    $return_names = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($return_names) ) {
        $selected[] = $row['name'];
        $position[] = $row['position'];
    }

            for ($i=0; sizeof($selected) > $i; $i++){
                 $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `team`(`selection_id`,`player_position`,`player_name`) VALUES ('selection_id\"\"','$position[$i]','$selected[$i]')") 
                 or die(mysql_error());
                 echo $selected[$i]; 
                 echo $position[$i];
                     echo'<br>';
   }
 var_dump($selected);
          }
```

Comment: thats not a database thats a table you should normalize a database

Comment: Thank you for your constructive comment. Made a typo when i asked the question